# strip_tags and trim not working together

Tags: php, html, trim, strip-tags

I need some help. I want to extract html tags and spaces, but this code not working. Where is my fault

Code in usage;

```
$ozellikpar = $ozellikler1[0]; 
echo strip_tags (trim($ozellikpar[13]));
```

Output;

```
<option value="">      Deneme</option>
```

But must be;

```
<option value="">Deneme</option>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Trim only removes whitespace from the ends of strings.

Comment: Can u show how the string is inside $ozellikpar[13] ?

Comment: Yes i know. I already want to delete the space at the beginning in option.

Comment: I get the strings with preg_match_all function. And i get this in array;

Makina[1]
Ev[2]
.
.
.
Deneme[13]

Comment: if the problem is only the white spaces before `deneme` you could just use a replace to remove white spaces and replace by nothing

`$elem = str_replace(" ", "", $ozellikpar[13]);`

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: I guess $ozelliklerpar[13] contains 'Deneme' string, right? Could you please let us know how does the rest of output is generated? I mean the html tag used to display the option. To be exact, where do `<option value="">` and `</option>` come from?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
echo trim(strip_tags ($ozellikpar[13]));
```